# Spring: Send email from Gmail

Tags: java, spring, email

I am following [This link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-with-attachment/) for sending email (Gmail smtp)
My problem is that why should I hardcode sender and receiver in the bean?

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
   <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
   <property name="port" value="587" />
   <property name="username" value="username" />
   <property name="password" value="password" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
     </property>
 </bean>

  <bean id="mailMail" class="com.mkyong.common.MailMail">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
        <property name="simpleMailMessage" ref="customeMailMessage" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="customeMailMessage"
class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">

       <property name="from" value="from@no-spam.com" />
       <property name="to" value="to@no-spam.com" />
       <property name="subject" value="Testing Subject" />
       <property name="text">
       <value>
        <![CDATA[
        Dear %s,
        Mail Content : %s
          ]]>
        </value>
           </property>
   </bean>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid hard coding the email properties by placing the email properties in an external properties file, say `email.properties`.  If you enable the `context` namespace within your configuration file Spring will load the properties file and allow properties within the file to be used via the expression language.

**Email.properties**

```
email.host=smtp.gmail.com
email.port=587
email.username=username
email.password=password
```

**Configuration File**

```
<!-- Spring Loads the Properties File, which can be used for resolution of EL Expressions -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:META-INF/db/db.properties"/>

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
   <property name="host" value="${email.host}" />
   <property name="port" value="${email.port}" />
   <property name="username" value="${email.username}" />
   <property name="password" value="${email.password}" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
     </property>
 </bean>
```

Comment: Thansk Kevin. Can I use same thing for "to"?

Comment: Yes, you could use this for any static string in your configuration file.

Answer (score 7):

if you test with gmail account, you need to enable the Access for less secure app option here:
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

otherwise you may get an authentication error.