# java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: [EOF](Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: [EOF])

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

I am trying to write a simple mail sender with usig *javax.mail*

**MailService:**

```
@Service
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Properties properties;

    private MailServiceImpl() {
        this.username ="my@gmail.com";
        this.password = "my";
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String body) {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Log:**

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet 2017-05-18 16:34:01,172 DEBUG - Could not complete request
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: [EOF]
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.service.impl.MailServiceImpl.sendMail(MailServiceImpl.java:46)
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.addUser(UserServiceImpl.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.addUser(Unknown Source)
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.web.UserController.registrationUser(UserController.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1354)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: [EOF]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1363)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.helo(SMTPTransport.java:836)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:375)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.service.impl.MailServiceImpl.sendMail(MailServiceImpl.java:44)
    ... 54 more
```

**Parameters:**

```
 public static final String TOPIC_REGISTRATION = "REGISTRATION";
 public static final String NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "Thank you for registration";

 mailService.sendMail(userMail,TOPIC_REGISTRATION,NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
```

**Question:**
Why I have this problem and how fix this problem?

*I known that it's a very popular question, but I can't find solution*

**Edit:**

```
@Service
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Properties properties;

    private MailServiceImpl() {
        this.username ="my@gmail.com";
        this.password = "my";
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "imap.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String body) {
        String host = "imap.gmail.com";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
        Store store = null;
        try {
            store = session.getStore("imap");
            store.connect(host, username, password);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Log:**

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection timed out: connect;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:479)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.service.impl.MailServiceImpl.sendMail(MailServiceImpl.java:37)
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.addUser(UserServiceImpl.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.addUser(Unknown Source)
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.web.UserController.registrationUser(UserController.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1354)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:84)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:87)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:446)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: Could you post the `body` contents?

Comment: properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); change '465' to '587'

Comment: @BrunoDM, yes please

Comment: @Afridi For **SSL** 465. Read this: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en&visit_id=1-636307131356843668-3101575453&rd=3

Comment: @studentST in configuration, you haven't specified 'TLS/STARTTLS' or 'SSL'

Comment: @Afridi this line *properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");*

Comment: Fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), follow these [Gmail instructions](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail), update your code above, and if it still doesn't work, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).

Comment: @BillShannon, I fix, but I can't understand where mistake and how solve this

Comment: You didn't post the JavaMail debug out.  Have you looked at the JavaMail [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug)?

Comment: @BillShannon Thank you so much. Problem solved

Comment: Maybe you should describe **how** you solved the problem so that the next person will know what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
<prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtps.localhost">'localhost'</prop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following properties:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

If it doesnt work, try chaning the port:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

Comment: Try to remove both mail.smtp.socketFactory.port and mail.smtp.socketFactory.class... See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260375/spring-send-email-from-gmail

Comment: Not a solution for me